# How to delete Safari cookies from OS 10.7.2 terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, cookies

I would like to delete all Safari cookies from terminal on Mac OS 10.7.2.

I tried to delete `~/Library/Cookie/Cookies.binarycookies` (this is the only file in `~/Library/Cookie`), but it didn't help.

Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to stop the `cookied` process. It's a user-specific process that manages cookies, and recreates the cookies database whenever it's deleted.

```
killall cookied
```

When you launch Safari the next time, `cookied` will not be able to recreate the `Cookies.binarycookies` file from memory and will start with an empty cookies database. The file that will be created then will effectively be empty (<1kb).

Comment: @Daniel Beck - are there other things that use `cookied` besides Safari?

Comment: @cwd Probably anything using [NSHTTPCookieStorage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSHTTPCookieStorage) directly or indirectly. Just guessing here though.

Comment: (for future readers, there does not seem to be a cookied process any longer in sierra, and deleting the Cookies.binarycookies file does seem to clear the cookies)

Answer (score 0):

Later versions of macOS have switched `cookied` with `nsurlstoraged`. Try:

```
rm -f ~/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies
pkill -U $(whoami) nsurlstoraged
```

Comment: Do you know if nsurlstoraged is still a thing, I don't see that running at all.