# Where does Safari 6 store cookies?

Tags: macos, safari, cookies

Seems like Safari 5 would store cookies in `~/Library/Cookies/Cookies.plist` - but cookies will remain present in Safari even after exiting Safari, removing this file, and then restarting Safari.

Where does Safari 6 store cookies?

[image: chocolate-cookies-07 1.jpg]

edit: corrected the path - Libraries (plural) was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `~/Library/Cookies/Cookies.plist` (note that it's *Library*, not *Libraries*) does not exist with Safari 6, and I'm pretty sure Safari 5.1 didn't use it anymore either.

Safari stores Cookies in `~/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies` now, which is no longer a plain text Preference List file, but a binary file from the `NSHTTPCookieStorage` class that is not human-readable.

If you want to decipher it and learn more about the file format, take a look at [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7816745/435093).

Comment: I still wonder why this file doesn't show up in fseventer when accessing websites.

Comment: It's shown by fseventer for me when for example refreshing this page, but it takes a few seconds.

Comment: I did see it in `sudo fs_events` with `grep -i cookie`, however I tried deleting this file (before asking the question) but it seems like it did not "clear the cookies" for Safari 6. Thoughts?

Comment: Should have mentioned what you've tried in your question. I'm pretty sure Safari stores the application state somewhere else as well @cwd – is your actual question how to delete cookies from the file system? If so, it'd be helpful to ask exactly that.

Comment: hmm, yes i should have. thanks! http://superuser.com/questions/376194/how-to-delete-safari-cookies-from-os-10-7-2-terminal